# Help me to prove the determinant formula

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, multilinear-algebra

Actually it is about the question of n-linear function, but it is so relevant to the determinant formula.

Here is the notation of the theorem.

If $n>1$ and $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix over $K$, we let $A(i|j)$ denote the $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ matrix obtained by deleting the $i$th row and $j$the column of $A$. If $D$ is an $(n-1)$-linear function and $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, we put $D_{ij}(A)= D[A(i|j)]$.

I want to prove the following theorem.

> > Let $n>1$ and let $D$ be an alternating $(n-1)$-linear function on $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ matrices over $K$. For each $j$, $1 \leq j \leq n$, the function $E_j$ defined by
> >     $$E_j(A) = \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i+j} A_{ij} D_{ij}(A)$$
> >     is an alternating $n$-linear function on $n \times n$ matrices $A$. If $D$ is a determinant function, so is each $E_j$.

The proof in my text says that "$D_{ij}(A)$ is independent of the $i$th row of $A$. Since $D$ is $(n-1)$-linear, it is clear that $D_{ij}$ is linear as a function of any row except row $i$. Therefore $A_{ij}D_{ij}(A)$ is an $n$-linear function of $A$."

I don't understand that $A_{ij}D_{ij}$ is $n$-linear function. Because $D_{ij}$ is not defined by the row $i$, and the column $j$, it is clearly $(n-1)$-linear function not $n$-linear function.

Help me to understand this.

Comment: The product $A_{ij}D_{ij}$ is $n $-linear because: (1) With respect to the $i $-th row of $A $, it is linear, since the first factor is linear while the second factor is constant. (2) With respect to any other row, it is linear, since the first factor is constant while the second factor is linear.

Comment: Oh! I see. Thanks.